# sublime text 4113: go to definition not working properly

Tags: sublimetext

I have updated the sublime text.

Now i have

```
class PetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Pet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PetSerializer
```

Now i can `ctrl + click` on `Pet` it takes me to the `Pet` model

but if i click on `viewsets` or `ModelViewSet` it does not take there.

I my project i have included the virtual env folder also.

Previously its working but after upgrade its not working

I want to sometimes see the source code also. Now go to definition is not working for all.

How to solve this

Comment: Does this also happen in [safe mode](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/safe_mode.html)?

Comment: what is safe_mode. this link does not work

Comment: Yes. Its happening in the sage mode also